# iPhone - forcing authentication form before Tabs views appear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm new to iOS development specifically for iPhone.
Here is my question, I've started coding Tabbed-Application, and I would like that when a user opens up the application he first enforced to see an authentication form (only in case he hasn't been authenticated before via server) and *ONLY* after he has logged on successfully he sees the different tabs.

How to do that?

I've already designed a storyboard with tabs and put some code, but I don't know how to combine it with the authentication form, should the form be part of the storyboard?

Would appreciate any answer especially with examples.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use Model navigation to open login page on first tab, when view controller open  as present view controller, tab bar will not show on screen. you can open login view either animation or not, its your choice.

thanks

Comment: I guess I need to somehow set this authentication view as "hidden" and enable it only until user login successfully and his credentials are stored internally. and from this point on this "authentication" view should be hidden.

Comment: Yes, you can do it but if you call another view controller as as present view controller via navigation controller. it will also work for you.

Comment: I have decided to to keep the TabViewController as the initial view controller. and created a XXXUITableViewController class and set it to the controller in the storyboard.
In the XXXAppleDelegate.didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I would like to load the UITableViewController as modal dialog, How can I do that??

I tried:
'code'
 XXXAuthenticationViewController * authenticationViewController = [[XXXAuthenticationViewController alloc] init];        
[self presentModalViewController:authenticationViewController animated:YES];
[authenticationViewController release];

Not working :-(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put authentication form in storyboard. Make it initial view controller from storyboard. After you done with authentication, you can change rootViewController of application window. Set your tabs view controller as rootViewController.

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:tabsViewController];
```

Comment: Does this view need to be Navigation Controller, or simply View Controller??

How about storing user credentials internally?? I read smewhere about "keychain" or something like that...

Comment: It depends on your requirements. If you don't have any navigation(like push some view on button tap) from Authentication form, you can use UIViewController. About keychain, I haven't used it yet. May be you can get help from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html

Comment: Let's say I would like to do the opposite, set the initial view controller to be the tabviewcontroller and in the AppDelegate check if user has provided authentication details (username+password). he he hasn't --> load the tableviewcontroller.
so this is my code:
'code'

        BTLAuthenticationViewController * authenticationViewController = [[BTLAuthenticationViewController alloc] init];


        [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:authenticationViewController];

When I run the app I see an empty table view, no controllers, why??

Comment: Is BTLAuthenticationViewController is table view controller? What do you mean by no controllers in table view?

Comment: Yes, BTLAuthenticationViewController is derived from UITableViewController.

by no controller appear, I mean that my table view is static of type "group" and I put 2 textfields. I cannot see anything - it's an empty table view horizontal lines.

Comment: Remove table view data source methods from your BTLAuthenticationViewController.m file.(http://code-ninja.org/blog/2012/02/11/ios-quick-tip-uitableview-with-static-cells-not-showing-up/)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I've already removed those sections from code. Let me describe you how my storyboard looks like: I have the main TabController with segue to 2 tabs. and I have another TableViewController (the static one) not connected to with any segue.
If I set this TableViewController to be initial then I see the textfields.

Comment: Try initializing authenticationViewController like this-  
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboard" bundle:nil];
    BTLAuthenticationViewController * authenticationViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BTLAuthenticationViewController"];
(http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thank you - I will try this and let you know :-)